# How to dockerize a third-party go application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Alongside the Docker containers running my micro-services written in `go` (one container per micro-service), I need to create a Docker container that runs the `Service Registry` service provided by a third-party framework (Koding's kontrol).

Having said that, I need to create a separate container that runs this third-party `go` application by executing the following commands.

1. Retrieve the application:

   `go get github.com/koding/kite/kontrol/kontrol`
2. Generate RSA key pair:

   `openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048`
   `openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout > key_pub.pem`
3. Set some environment variables:

   `KONTROL_PORT=6000
   KONTROL_USERNAME="kontrol"
   KONTROL_STORAGE="etcd"
   KONTROL_KONTROLURL="http://127.0.0.1:6000/kite"
   KONTROL_PUBLICKEYFILE="certs/key_pub.pem"
   KONTROL_PRIVATEKEYFILE="certs/key.pem"`
4. Initialize the `Registry Service`:

   `./bin/kontrol -initial`
5. Start the `Registry Service`:

   `./bin/kontrol`

How do I include these steps in my project? For instance, I have a `docker-composer.yaml` file like this:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  api:
    container_name: 'api'
    build: './api'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - './api:/go/src/app'
    depends_on:
      - 'mongo'
  etcd0:
    container_name: 'etcd0'
    image: 'quay.io/coreos/etcd'
    command: >
      etcd -name etcd0
      -advertise-client-urls http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
      -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001
      -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://127.0.0.1:2380
      -listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380
      -initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1
      -initial-cluster etcd0=http://127.0.0.1:2380
      -initial-cluster-state new
  mongo:
    container_name: 'mongo'
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - '/var/lib/mongodb:/var/lib/mongodb'
```

Comment: We're not here to write your code (or docker config) for you. Please show us what you have tried, and what problems you encountered.

Comment: You have pretty much written down the whole Dockerfile in the question. What's the problem? I don't know what that key pair is used for, but in general it is a horrible idea to bake keys into an image.